# Page faults in Linux, how to resolve?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, ubuntu

I get a error and I dont have ideia what mean and what to do now. I try this code in AWS ubuntu:`sudo time docker checkpoint create --checkpoint-dir=/home/ubuntu/exec/checkpoint/ --leave-running=true container_2 checkpoint0`, but the output was:

> 0:00.07elapsed 15%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 15024maxresident)k 0inputs+0outputs (0major+1410minor)pagefaults 0swaps

but the correct output was:

> real   0m0.071s
> user    0m0.010s
> sys     0m0.000s

Comment: What error? That's just `time`'s output.

Comment: the correct output is 'real 0m0.071s user 0m0.010s sys 0m0.000s', but my output was  "0:00.07elapsed 15%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 15024maxresident)k 0inputs+0outputs (0major+1410minor)pagefaults 0swaps'"   I want the real time, in this example is real0m0.071s and my output is 0:00.07, its the same real time, or different?